# Find the matrix of a linear transformation and check if its matrix is defective

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the matrix of a linear transformation $\mathcal{A}(p(x))=        \begin{bmatrix}
        p(1)-p(-1)  \\
        p'(1)+p'(-1)+p''(2)  \\
        \end{bmatrix},p(x)\in\mathcal{P_2}(x)$ where $\mathcal{P_2}$ is the space of polynomials $p(x)$ and $p^{'}(x)$ is a derivative of $p(x)$.

If $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$,

$\mathcal{A}(p(x))=        \begin{bmatrix}
        2b  \\
        -4  \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

$[\mathcal{A}]=\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 2 & 0  \\
        0 & 0 & -4  \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

Is it possible for non-squared matrix to be defective (non-diagonalizable)?

Comment: Non-squared matrices are not endomorphisms, but maps between two vector spaces that cannot be identified. So even the concept of "eigenvector" should be meaningless to them.

Comment: @G. Sassatelli Does the mapping of $\mathcal{A}$ needs to be a square matrix?

Comment: As I've learned it, only square matrices can be diagonalised. Yours is defined as a map $$\mathcal A\,:\,\mathcal P_2\cong\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^2$$ Hence, it is not represented by a square matrix.